# Modulo alternative Lua

Tags: lua, modulo

I don't have much coding experience so I don't really know of an efficient alternative to modulo, the issue I have is that I want to have the same funcionality but witouth it ever returning zero if that makes sense.

So I have an arbritary value % 8 and I want my results to go (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,etc)

any help or push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Modulo returns a remainder, in your case, from 0-7, so maybe modulo + 1?

Comment: you specifically say "efficient alternative" but did not describe how modulo is not efficient for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to make indices from `1` to `8` loop. For zero-based offsets from `0` to `7` this would be trivial by using `i % 8`; consider simply making your table zero-based.

For one-based indices, the simplest way to go is to first subtract `1` to make it zero-based, then apply the modulo to wrap around, then add `1` to make it one-based again: `((i - 1) % 8) + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

> So I have an arbritary value % 8 and I want my results to go
> (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,etc)

```
local result = value % 8 + 1
```

This is a simple maths problem. If one arrithmetic operator doesn't give you the desired result, use or add others to your formula.